# How Can I Set Video Splash Screen in react native android

Tags: react-native

I am Developing Sample Application, But i want a video splash (in this Video Duration is 8 sec.) , Actually I  am Setting Splash page,But now i want to set to  Video Splash.

splashPage.js file

This is My Code.
import Video from 'react-native-video';

```
//import Main from './main';
import LoginScreen from './App/Components/login.js';
class SplashPage extends Component {

componentWillMount () {
        var navigator = this.props.navigator;
        setTimeout (() => {

          navigator.replace({
                component: LoginScreen,
                 // <-- This is the View you go to
            });
        }, 5000);     //<-- Time until it jumps to "MainView"
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>

               <View>{StatusBar.setBackgroundColor('black', true)}</View>
               <Video source={require('./images/splashVideo.mp4')}
                     style={{position: 'absolute',
                             top: 0,
                             left: 0,
                             right: 0,
                             bottom: 0,
                             opacity: 0.3}}
                             muted={true}
                             repeat={true}
                             resizeMode="cover"      />
               {/*<Image style={{ width: windowSize.width, height: windowSize.height}} source={require('./images/splash.png')}></Image>*/} 
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Thanks In Advance,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's integrate video component into your splash screen:

1) Install the node module:

```
npm install react-native-video --save or yarn add react-native-video --save
```

2) Import the video component in your splash screen component:

```
`import Video from 'react-native-video'
```

3) Inside the splash screen's `render()` function put video component

```
<Video source={require('path of video')}
                     style={{position: 'absolute',
                             top: 0,
                             left: 0,
                             right: 0,
                             bottom: 0,
                             opacity: 0.3}}
                             muted={true}
                             repeat={true}
                             resizeMode="cover"              
          />
```

Edits:

```
import LoginScreen from './App/Components/login.js';
import Video from 'react-native-video'

class SplashPage extends Component {

componentWillMount () {
        var navigator = this.props.navigator;
        setTimeout (() => {

          navigator.replace({
                component: LoginScreen,
                 // <-- This is the View you go to
            });
        }, 5000);     //<-- Time until it jumps to "MainView"
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center',width:null,height:null}}>
               <Video source={require('./images/splashVideo.mp4')}
                     style={{position: 'absolute',
                             top: 0,
                             left: 0,
                             right: 0,
                             bottom: 0,
                             opacity: 0.3}}
                             muted={true}
                             repeat={true}
                             resizeMode="cover"      />
               <View>{StatusBar.setBackgroundColor('black', true)}</View> 
               {/*<Image style={{ width: windowSize.width, height: windowSize.height}} source={require('./images/splash.png')}></Image>*/} 
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Back button integration:

```
BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
            const { navigator } = this.props
            var routes = navigator.getCurrentRoutes()

            if(routes[routes.length - 1].id == 'main' || routes[routes.length - 1].id == 'login') {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                this.popRoute();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Cheers:)

Comment: I added my page Splash Screen page.js

Comment: How Can I add this

Comment: How Can I Get BackGround Score

Comment: Hey I got A Background Score  Like As Property as  muted={false}

Comment: Do you Know BackAndroid like Back Handler?

Comment: yeah.. you want to integrate that ?

Comment: yes Actually I have A Issue When I was click on Back Button it's comina Main page and Login page aslo Getting Some Times

Comment: BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
        var navigator=this.props.navigator;
            if(navigator.getCurrentRoutes().length>2) {
                 navigator.pop()
                return true // exit app
              }
              else {
                return false // do not exit app
              } 
    });

Comment: this is my Code

Comment: Image Issue:After That Ima using image Picker and File Upload this is Not a Fit the Image Modal pop up i used image Properties like resizeMode:'cover '/stretch/ or contain

Comment: but not fit the image @CodeSingh

Comment: I have Two Issues  those Two Are Back button and Image Not fit in Model PopUp

Comment: in which screen a backbutton is ?

Comment: I am Using Main Page

Comment: when you press back button then it comes to login screen ?

Comment: Firstly When I was Login , Go to Main Page.
In Main Page Contains Some  Grid and Same As Menu Also , After that When I was Click on Grid View Inside One Item Go to next Page and After next Page Click on Another Page.Okay, After that When I was Come Back Using Back Button , it's Coming one by one  Page , Finally I reached main page and after app not clsoing ,going to login page, CodeSingh.That Is my issue.(Actually In this Scenairo when I go back to Main Page App is Closing, But it's Going to Login Page)

Comment: Did You Get it my Point?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44414389/how-can-i-get-gender-in-react-native-android

Comment: this.popRoute()

Comment: getting Error like undefined not an Object  this2.popRoute()  & what is login and main

Comment: this.popRoute() is a function which pop routes from the stack.. you can add your own in that place...

Comment: I didn't get it

Comment: Hi Singh I Used Video Tag in Splash video comes it's fine but below 5 and 5 version Devices not  show the Video

Comment: I don't know anything about this, maybe you can raise this issue in the git repo of react native video..

Comment: Is this doable at expo?